# Firebase crash reporting not working in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting, firebase-console

I tried  to integrate Firebase Crash reporter in my project.Here is a my gradle source.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.0.5'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.1.2"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```

}

```
 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
```

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "**********"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 24
    versionName "1.0.24"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.buy_tickets_verification_view.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    multiDexEnabled true

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

  }
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.koushikdutta.urlimageviewhelper:urlimageviewhelper:1.0.4'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
compile('com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0') {
    force = true;
}
compile('com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0') {
    force = true;
}
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0') {
    force = true;
}
compile('com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0') {
    force = true;
}
compile('com.android.support:design:26.1.0') {
    force = true;
}
compile('com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0') {
    force = true;
}
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'
compile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
compile 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'

compile 'me.neavo:volley:2014.12.09'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here is a source.
I don't know why,but first time when I integrated Firebase crash log,it's worked perfect,but now,I can's see my errors in dashboard.
It's a strange situation,I don't know what's a wrong in my source

What am i doing wrong?
Thanks everyone

Comment: You have to call "crashanalytics" in catch statement where you are getting exception. And check on which line of code it causing exception and at that place you have used crashanalytics or not

Comment: @ankitpatidar the OP is not using crashlytics and is use the regular firebase crash reporting